# Java Interface does not take into consideration method implementation from the super class

Tags: java, design-patterns, strategy-pattern

The following example with ducks, is based on the Head First design patterns book.

I have a game with different types of ducks. There is a super class Duck and it has two behaviours: fly and quack, which are stored in fields. The concrete classes decide (in the constructor) which behaviour a concrete breed has (see MalardDuck class).

I realised I want my ducks to not only have type Duck but also Quackable (so that I can have methods that accept only quackables - assuming that there are other types that quack - see Lake class). When I implement the interface in MallardDuck, the compiler complains that the class does not have the method quack although it is defined in its superclass - Duck class.

Now I could think of two solutions:

1. Overwrite a method quack by just calling the method from the superclass: super.quack() <- but that seems unnecessary (in theory) - a child class has a direct access to superclass's public methods, so why the interface Quackable even complains...?
2. Make Duck implement the Quackable -> this is rather illogical cause some Ducks don't Quack (their quackBehaviour is implemented with SiletnQuack class).

However in both solutions the duck:

- HAS A quackable behaviour, AND
- IS A quackable

Isn't that fundamentally wrong? What am I missing?

```
abstract class Duck{
    protected Flyiable flyBehaviour;
    protected Quackable quackBehaviour;
    public void quack(){
        quackBehaviour.quack();
    }
    void performFly(){
        flyBehaviour.fly();
    }
    void swim(){
        // swimming implementation
    }
    abstract void display();
}
interface Quackable{
    void quack();
}
class Quack implements Quackable{

    @Override
    public void quack() {
        System.out.println("Quack!");
    }
}
class Quack implements Quackable{

    @Override
    public void quack() {
        System.out.println("Quack!");
    }
}
class SilentQuack implements Quackable{

    @Override
    public void quack() {
        System.out.println("...");
    }
}
class MallardDuck extends Duck{
    public MallardDuck(){
        quackBehaviour = new Quack();
        flyBehaviour = new FlyWithWings();
    }

    @Override
    void display() {

        // it looks like a Mallard duck
    }
}
```

What if I want to accept ducks to this method as quackables (along with other animals):

```
class Lake{
    ArrayList<Quackable> quackingAnimals;
    void addQuackingAnimal(Quackable animal){
        quackingAnimals.add(animal);
    }
    void displayQuackables(){
        //...
    }
}
```

Solution 1:

```
class MallardDuck extends Duck implements Quackable {
    public MallardDuck(){
        quackBehaviour = new Quack();
        flyBehaviour = new FlyWithWings();
    }

    @Override
    void display() {

        // it looks like a Mallard duck
    }

    @Override
    public void quack() {
        super.quack();
    }
}
```

Solution 2:

```
abstract class Duck implements Quackable{
    protected Flyiable flyBehaviour;
    protected Quackable quackBehaviour;
    public void quack(){
        quackBehaviour.quack();
    }
    void performFly(){
        flyBehaviour.fly();
    }
    void swim(){
        // swimming implementation
    }
    abstract void display();
}
```

Comment: seeing as you want all your ducks to be quackable, why would you try to add it on the subclasses? you might create a new subclass and forget to have it implement quackable

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is because `Duck` class DOES NOT implement the `quack` method from the `Quackable` interface. Although it has a `quack` method with the same signature, it is not the same method, that is declared in the interface.

I do not understand, why Solution 2 (making the `Duck` class implement `Quackable` interface) would be illogical - it does expose public method for quacking, so all of it's descendants will `quack` anyway (but with different `quack` that is declared in the `Quackable` interface). In my opinion (only opinion), the `Duck` class should implement `Quackable`.

If (in your case) not all `Ducks` `quack`, then it is reasonable, that a `Duck` can't be treated as something that has `Quackable` behavior and thus it can't be added to the collection of `Quackable` objects. In this case (in my opinion) you could create another abstract class extending `Duck` and implementing `Quackable` interface (like `QuackingDuck`) and in this case (in my opinion) you should remove `quack` method from `Duck` class - as not all `Ducks` `quack`.

I hope that it answers your question. To sum up:

- the `quack` method from `Duck` is not the implementation of the `quack` method from `Quackable` interface (as it would be the case in e.g. JavaScript)
- in current implementation all `Ducks` `quack`, only their `quacking` behavior (implementation) is different (and in the case of `SilentDuck` - it still `quacks`)

Answer (score 0):

[In the context of your question, I prefer to use the term "delegate" over "behaviour", because I personally think it better conveys the concept.]

Your interface `Quackable` effectively means "something that can quack".

And even the original `Duck` abstract class had that method, so it already followed that interface, but you "forgot" to declare that fact. In a consistent world, you should have had `Duck` implement `Quackable` right from the beginning.

Regarding HAS and IS:

All `Ducks` have some `quack()` method, so effectively they ARE `Quackable` (in the meaning of "something that can quack"). It doesn't matter how they decide about their quack() implementation, using the inherited delegation method, modifying the inherited version by supplying a different delegete/behaviour, or overriding the method.

The fact that they have the `quack()` ability defines them as BEING `Quackable`.

Your Duck subclasses also HAVE a `Quackable` and use it as a delegate, deferring the real quacking to some other "behaviour" instance (like politicians who don't publish their opinions himself, but by having a spokesperson).

So, there's nothing wrong about a class BEING `Quackable` and HAVING `Quackable` at the same time. In the real world, we all ARE LivingCreatures, and many of us HAVE LivingCreatures as our pets.

One remark on behaviour objects:

Though this pattern can be useful, be aware that you loose the ability (or at least make it quite complicated) to make the `quack()` behaviour depend on the Duck's state (e.g. sound differently if on water or in the air).

Answer (score 0):

You are having the same method in both superclass and interface. The `quack()` method in MallardDuck class **does 2 things at one time**:

1. Override `quack()` in the superclass Duck
2. Implement `quack()` in the Quackable interface.

Solution 2 helps you to avoid this situation.